# Probability of getting head in the first coin

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I have come across this problem and would like to know how you would solve it:

> $n$ coins are tossed one after the other. The probability of a coin getting head is $p$. If we got $k$ heads, what is the probability of the first coin being head?

Now, I believe the solution would be simply $k/n$ given that the event of getting $k$ heads is assured, but on the other hand that would be too easy and the probability p would not be used at all, which is somehow strange. I do not think a conditional probability approach is right, though.

Comment: $p$ doesn't matter because the coins have already been tossed.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mention seems to be correct and smart. A more pedantic way following the definitions can be the following.

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be the $n$ iid random variables corresponding to each coin tossing.
Assume tail is $0$ and head is $1$.

The quantity we are after is
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=1|X_1+\dots+X_n=k)=\frac{\mathbb P(X_1=1\text{ and }X_1+\dots+X_n=k)}{\mathbb P(X_1+\dots+X_n=k)}.
$$

Now
$$
\mathbb P(X_1+\dots+X_n=k)={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=1\text{ and }X_1+\dots+X_n=k)=
\mathbb P(X_1=1\text{ and }X_2+\dots+X_n=k-1)={{n-1}\choose {k-1}}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
so the result is indeed $k/n$.

Comment: lets assume that $n=5$ , $k=2$ , $p= 2/3$ , then the result is $$C(4,1) \times (2/3)^2 \times (1/3)^3 =16/243$$ is is not equal to $4/5$ .

Comment: I understood that the OP wanted to compute the conditional probability, which is the ratio of the probability of the intersection ($16/243$ as you say) over the probability of the event we are conditioning on ($40/243$), yielding $16/40=2/5$